# Picture size 0x0 is invalid in FFMPEG log

Tags: ffmpeg

In my program I'm trying to decode an MPEG4 stream from a certain url and the decoding fails. Strangely, MPEG4 streams from other urls are decoded fine, so it's not a problem of the absence of the codec.

Here's how I decode:

1) Find the decoder:

```
   AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
```

2) Allocate a context

```
 ACodecContext* ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(0);
```

3) Open the codec

```
avcodec_open2(ctx, codec, 0) // it returns > 0, fine
```

4) Decoding a packet (which I have)

```
   avcodec_decode_video2(ctx, frame, &decoded, &packet);
```

Now `avcodec_decode_video2` fails returning `-1` and FFMPEG log prints:

**Picture size 0x0 is invalid
get_buffer() failed (-1 0 0x0)**

If I manually set up `ctx->width` and `ctx->height` before decoding to the correct values (I know the dimensions of the picture) then it decodes fine.

But I can not be sure of the dimensions all the time, therefore I would like to know if I can overcome the -1 error.

By seeing the FFMPEG log output can anyone suggest something for me to do?

Comment: what's the streaming protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does the file have a correct VOL header? You will face this problem if it does not. The VOL header has the height and width.

Comment: It's a network stream not a file. I'll check and let you know